# Connecting 3 screen to a computer while the third is in a large distance from the others

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card, gpu, vga, dvi

I have win 7 with Ultramon (multiple screen software), and Radeon HD6450 GPU (NOT THE FLEX VERSION) and 3 LCD's of the same kind (LG E2242TC LED) - two of them in the desk, and the third is in other room (about 5 meters more or less).

Due to circumstances I CANNOT replace the current GPU nor adding other one, whether to the motherboard or one of usb.

The setup I did was to connect first screen with DVI to the first GPU input.
The second GPU input was connected to a VGA Video splitter (active), with which I connected the second and the third distance screen (I needed to *mirror* the second to the third).

This setup worked fine (with some tolerated flickers on the second and third screen) 
until recently, when everything is fine for 2 minutes, and then horrible flickers start
to arouse in the second and the third screen.

Because of this, I thought of switching to DVI: replacing the long VGA cable and replacing the
VGA video splitter to DVI Y CABLE.

Does this kind of setup will solve the problem?
If not any other suggestion?

Thank you!

EDIT:

The card,monitors and cables are tested and are OK! I suspect the problem is with the Video splitter - I can buy a new one, but what if it will fail again?

Also, before I used the VGA SPLITTER, I used a VGA Y splitter , with which there were massive flickering , and because of this I concluded that because of the length, I should use active VGA splitter...

After some test I see that if I connect 2 screen -> 1 dvi the vga the screen connected to the VGA has some flickering, but if only one screen connected - does not matter which - whether the distance screen or one of the other - everything is OK - Is the problem in the GPU?

Comment: Why do you think it is flickering first? Bad cable, bad card, bad monitor, interference from room/other source?

Comment: The card,monitors and cables are tested and are OK! I suspect the problem is with the Video splitter - I can buy a new one, but what if it will fail again?

Comment: This is really important to know. Please [update your question](http://superuser.com/posts/603956/edit) and include this information (that it has been tested). How much is a new splitter? Your question is hard to answer, other than "if the cable is cheap, buy it and try it!" However, it is worrying that it started off ok and now bad, suggests the fault could be else where but you say you've tested everything else. I wonder if the fault is with the card or the connection to the motherboard maybe

Answer (score 0):

DVI can run about 4,5 metres without issue @ 1920 x 1200, and the DVI signal is a lot more stable (less susceptible to electrical interference), however you need to make sure you have a good splitter. I am assuming that the second two monitors are supposed to display the same image, as I'm not sure you can use a single output to do do dual independent monitors.

Comment: After some test I see that if I connect 2 screen -> 1 dvi the vga the screen connected to the VGA has some flickering, but if only one screen connected - does not matter which - whether the distance screen or one of the other - everything is OK - Is the problem in the GPU?

Comment: It might very well be, possibly the GPU isn't able to provide a solid signal when two monitors are drawing it.. or possibly the two monitors are slightly out of alignment in their timings, so while the GPU can vary things to keep one monitor going, two will be divided (maybe even the different cable lengths are at fault here)..